# Uniform convergence for functions with jumps

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

We know that Fourier partial sums (integrals) do not converge uniformly for BV functions with jumps due to [Gibb's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). Is there any other types of sums/procedures that use only Fourier coefficients to produce a sequence of functions which converge uniformly (except isolated points) without exhibiting Gibb's phenomenon? I am not asking for approximations, but for uniform convergence except at isolated points (the exact points of jumps).

Clarify : Suppose $f$ has jump at $x_0$, then the sequence should still converge uniformly in the interval $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$, any $\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}$ taken such that $f$ has no jumps in $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$. This does not happen with Fourier partial sums.

Comment: Any method with positive kernel has no Gibb's phenomenon.  For example if  $f $ is uniformly continuous and bounded in $ (x - \epsilon,  x)$ and has a jump discontinuity at x, then the (C, 1) mean of the Fourier series of f  converges uniformly to f in $(x -\epsilon, x)$.   The following function $ f(x) = (\pi -x)$/2 for $0 < x < 2 \pi$ , $ f(0) = 0$   and extended by periodicity to all of R, is an example, here the interval is $(0-\epsilon, 0)$, | $\epsilon $ |  $ < \pi $ . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{ f_{n} \}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is necessarily continuous on $[a,b]$. It is the general theorem that results in the non-uniform convergence of the Fourier series for a function $f$ that is not continuous on $[a,b]$.

Specifically, the Fourier series $\{ S_{n}^{f} \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of continuous functions
$$
          S_{n}^{f}(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)e^{-int}dt\right]e^{inx}
$$
If $f$ is piecewise smooth on an interval $[a,b]$ with one discontinuity in $(a,b)$, then the Fourier series cannot converge uniformly on $[a,b]$. In that case, the logical negation of uniform convergence must be true--namely, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $N$, there exists $n \ge N$ and $x\in [a,b]$ for which $|f(x)-S_{N}^{f}(x)| \ge \epsilon$.

Comment: I've mentioned that except at isolated points. Please see my "clarify note" in question specifically.

Comment: Also Ive never said the said sequence of functions need to be continuous!

Comment: @RajeshD : If it converged uniformly in $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$ and in $(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$ and it converged at $x_0$ to something, then the convergence would be uniform on $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thats fine, i want that to happen

Comment: Please note the sequence of functions need not be continuous.

Comment: @RajeshD If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly on $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$, then the limit is necessarily continuous on $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$, which prevents it from converging to $f$ on those intervals if $f$ is continuous on $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)\cup(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$, has left- and right-hand limits at $x_0$ with a simple jump.

Comment: The functions need not be continuous, fourier sums are continuous but ours need not be.

Comment: @RajeshD : Fourier coefficients cannot distinguish the values of $f$ at a single point or at any finite number of points. Do you want there to be a fixed set of functions $\{ g_{n} \}$ from which you construct a sum of some type? That might be strong enough to lead to a contradiction ... not sure.